# Working with multiple displays?

Tags: cocoa, objective-c-2.0, multiple-monitors, multiscreen

I have zero experience with **multiple displays & cocoa**. Feel free to share any handy links, tutorials. What I need is this : **I'm trying to fill all displays with a full screen, transparent window**. What I'm afraid for, though, is that all the displays together don't necessarily form a rectangle, but have to touch somewhere.

What are your thoughts about this?

Comment: Yes, the screens don't have to form a rectangle (think e.g. MacBook with bigger external monitor as secondary display). You need one per monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would set up a window for each display that is not mirrored. The API you are looking for is "Quartz Display Services".

`CGGetActiveDisplayList` gives you a list of non-sleeping, non-mirrored, drawable displays.